# "Value larger than specified precision" importing file with PDI

Tags: oracle, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to use Pentaho Data Integration to import a file into an Oracle database.

The transformation that fails attempts to insert into the database the information that receives from a file/input stream. The transformation type is `Table Output`.

The problem is that one of the columns in the file has a value that exceeds the capacity of the Oracle column, I get:

> 2019/03/12 22:00:01 - Insert into Bank Reference Data.0 - Error batch
> inserting rows into table [REF_DATA].
>
> 2019/03/12 22:00:01 - Insert into Bank Reference Data.0 - Errors encountered (first 10):
>
> 2019/03/12 22:00:01 - Insert into Bank Reference Data.0 - ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
>
> 2019/03/12 22:00:01 - Insert into Bank Reference Data.0 -
>
> 2019/03/12 22:00:01 - Insert into Bank Reference Data.0 -
>
> 2019/03/12 22:00:01 - Insert into Bank Reference Data.0 - Error updating batch

The file has 100 columns and 5000 rows, and the error message is not telling me which column is the one that fails. I tried to log with debug level and I don't see the name of the column either. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the transformation had batch updates = true, changing the batch updates to false printed the row that had the problem.